# Bundles/images/user-img-background.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I use ASP.NET MVC 5 template with multi page application and EF, after publish and deploy to IIS(Win Server 2012), I can login successfully, however, some resources cannot be loaded (click F12, and check chrome console):

```
fontawesome-webfont.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
user-img-background.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
fontawesome-webfont.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
fontawesome-webfont.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

If F5 refresh, the detail of one error is as following:
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Bundles/images/user-img-background.jpg 404 (Not Found)

ASP.NET bundle is enabled, the user-img-background.jpg is referenced (project folder/css/style.css):

background: url("../images/user-img-background.jpg") no-repeat no-repeat;

the user-img-background.jpg is in (project folder/images/user-img-background.jpg).

BundleConfig is as following:

```
bundles.Add(
                new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/account-vendor/css")
                    .Include("~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
                    .Include("~/css/style.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            );

            bundles.Add(
                new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/vendor/css")
                .Include("~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
                .Include("~/css/style.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            );
```

Also I checked the MIME types in IIS are all added.

Any help?

Comment: When you browse the published website, do you see a successful network call to `Bundles/account-vendor/css` in chrome developer tools?

Comment: I can see /Bundles/vendor/css/… but no /Bundles/account-vendor/css/... when I hove on a name in css tab. but in img tab, there is an error "user-img-backgroun.jpg 404 text/html (index) 2.8KB....

Comment: Is this issue present only on production (i.e. minify optimization enabled) or it is always present?